# Play Flv file in Prettyphoto

Tags: flowplayer, prettyphoto

I am using flowplayer and using that i am playing the flv file on Fancy box and  Colorbox but it did not work in prettyphoto . it is displaying Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exist.while same code running in the fancybox and colorbox.

Thank you for help
bhupendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works for me is:
I have made changes in the Prettyphoto.js , what i have done is that , i have find the "flash" and make its return type to "iframe" .